# Is there any program to provide a consistent interface across multiple archive types?

Tags: command-line, archive, compression

At the moment, if I download a compressed file, it could be any of a .tar.gz archive, a tar.bz2 arhive, a .zip archive or a .gz archive. And each time I do so, I have to remember what the command line options for that program are.

Is there any CLI program where I can just go:

undocompression somefile.??

and let it figure out what format the archive is in? (overly long name used to avoid conflicting with any real program)

Comment: I couldn't find or create any tags such as `archive`, `compression` etc. Could someone else add the correct one?

Comment: @Tshepang: Fixed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [p7zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/files/). It automatically identifies the archive type and decompress it.

> p7zip is the command line version of
>   [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org) for Unix/Linux, made by an
>   independent developer.

`7z e <file_name>`

Answer (score 7):

I found this little snippet a while ago and have been using it since.  I just have it in my .bashrc file

```
extract () {
if [ -f $1 ] ; then
    case $1 in
        *.tar.bz2)  tar xjf $1      ;;
        *.tar.gz)   tar xzf $1      ;;
        *.bz2)      bunzip2 $1      ;;
        *.rar)      rar x $1        ;;
        *.gz)       gunzip $1       ;;
        *.tar)      tar xf $1       ;;
        *.tbz2)     tar xjf $1      ;;
        *.tgz)      tar xzf $1      ;;
        *.zip)      unzip $1        ;;
        *.Z)        uncompress $1   ;;
        *)          echo "'$1' cannot be extracted via extract()" ;;
    esac
else
    echo "'$1' is not a valid file"
fi
}
```

Comment: This is more effective than the accepted answer, since `7z e foo.tar.gz` just leaves you with a `foo.tar` file.

Answer (score 4):

In Debian/Ubuntu there is the `unp` package, which is a Perl script that acts as a frontend for many archiving utilities.

Answer (score 4):

From [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4367/extracting-nested-zip-files): [atool](http://www.nongnu.org/atool/), which also handles various archive types and is more powerful than `unp` because it also handles listing of contents, finding differences between archives etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think `ark` the *KDE archiving tool* can be run without a GUI. From the `ark` manpage

```
ark --batch archive.tar.bz2
```

*Will extract archive.tar.bz2 into the current directory without showing any GUI.*

Arks support of various archive formats depends on which apps you have installed (e.g. for rar it depends on unrar ), but I don't know of any formats it can't handle.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised no one mentioned the [dtrx](https://brettcsmith.org/2007/dtrx/) tool that was suggested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341308/18669).

Seems to fit the request to a tee.

Answer (score 2):

GNU tar (and star) has at least some compression auto-detection capabilities:

```
tar xf foo.tar.gz
tar xf foo.tar.bz
```

just work.

Comment: It does depend on the version of tar which formats it can autodetect but other than that it works well... IIRC `star` is actually a more standardized way, where GNU's tar is a non standard extension.

Comment: Latest version of GNU tar can uncompress all compressed archives, which are created with any of the compression filter switches (z, j, J, --lzma), it will detect compression automatically.

Comment: @xenoterracide: Well, the author of star has criticized GNU tar a lot in his usual style - these writings could be biased (ignoring bad points about star and good points about GNU tar), contain probably some FUD and are probably outdated.

Answer (score 2):

[The Unarchiver](https://theunarchiver.com/) supports extraction of about 50 different formats with a consistent interface.

By default, a directory is created if there              is more than one top-level file or folder.

[View its `man`-page](https://manned.org/unar).

The command line version supports Linux and is available [here](https://theunarchiver.com/command-line).