# Bash loop unzip passworded file script

Tags: linux, shell-script, password, zip

I'm trying to make a script that will unzip a password protected file, the password being the name of the file that I will get when unzipping

Eg.

- file1.zip contains file2.zip and its password is file2.
- file2.zip contains file3.zip and its password is file3

How do I unzip `file1.zip`, and read the name of `file2.zip` so it can be entered in the script?

Here's a screenshot of the command line:
[image: Here's a screenshot of what I meant]

> ```
> root@kaliVM:~/Desktop# unzip 49805.zip  
> Archive:  49805.zip  
> [49805.zip]  13811.zip password:
> ```

I just need Bash to read that output in order to know the new password
(In this case the password is 13811).

Here's what I've done so far

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo First zip name:
read firstfile


pw=$(zipinfo -1 $firstfile | cut -d. -f1)
nextfile=$(zipinfo -1 $firstfile)
unzip -P $pw $firstfile

rm $firstfile
nextfile=$firstfile
```

Now how can I make it do the loop?

Comment: Is it just one file in the initial zipped file and so just file2.zip in file1.zip?

Comment: Yes, every zip contains a single zip with more than 100 zips in total.

Comment: So this is a zip file that's nested 100 levels deep? Or it's one zip file that contains 100 zip files?

Comment: (or you have 100 zip files to unzip in the current directory)?

Comment: It's a file that's nested X levels deep. I just need it to keep unzipping untill it can't unzip anymore.

Comment: @molinskeh, I've updated my answer with a shell loop to recursively unzip such a file

Comment: [it's vs its](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/its-or-it-s) - so its password is...

Comment: Is `fcrackzip` in-scope? If so, don't even bother to ask the user for the file passwords :)

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz sorry I don't quite get the question/answer?

Comment: @molinskeh Sorry, it was a joke because ZIP encryption is easily breakable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't have and cannot install `zipinfo` for any reason, you can imitate it by using `unzip` with `-Z` option. To list the contents of the zip use `unzip -Z1`:

```
pw="$(unzip -Z1 file1.zip | cut -f1 -d'.')" 
unzip -P "$pw" file1.zip
```

Put it to a loop:

```
zipfile="file1.zip"
while unzip -Z1 "$zipfile" | head -n1 | grep "\.zip$"; do
    next_zipfile="$(unzip -Z1 "$zipfile" | head -n1)"
    unzip -P "${next_zipfile%.*}" "$zipfile"
    zipfile="$next_zipfile"
done
```

or a recursive function:

```
unzip_all() {
    zipfile="$1"
    next_zipfile="$(unzip -Z1 "$zipfile" | head -n1)"
    if echo "$next_zipfile" | grep "\.zip$"; then
        unzip -P "${next_zipfile%%.*}" "$zipfile"
        unzip_all "$next_zipfile"
    fi
}
unzip_all "file1.zip"
```

---

> -Z     zipinfo(1) mode.  If the first option on the command line is -Z, the remaining options are taken to be zipinfo(1) options.  See the appropriate manual page for a description of these options.
>
> -1  :   list filenames only, one per line.  This option excludes all others; headers, trailers and zipfile comments are never printed.  It is intended for use in Unix shell scripts.

Comment: Awesome it worked, thank you!

Btw in the loop function, why did you grep "\.zip$", head -n1 spits out the same output every time with or without grep. Also what does %%.* mean on the 4th line of the loop function?

Comment: actually `%%.*` should be  `%.*`, I changed that. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/7365127 for explanation what it does.

Comment: `| grep "\.zip$"` gives same output, but returns true when .zip found and false when not found => As I use it in the `if` or `while` statement, this return value will stop the function when ".zip" is not found anymore.

Answer (score 8):

Ask [`zipinfo`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zipinfo) for the filename listed in the zip file, then capture it for the password. Use that password to unzip the file:

```
pw=$(zipinfo -1 file1.zip | cut -d. -f1)
unzip -P "$pw" file1.zip
```

Note that the flag to `zipinfo` is a *one* not an *ell*.

Borrowing liberally from [Gilles' answer to a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4372/117549), here's a bash loop that will extract a password-protected nested zip file until there are no more zip files:

```
shopt -s nullglob
while set -- *.zip; [ $# -eq 1 ]
do 
  unzippw "$1" && rm -- "$1"
done
```

Where I've defined the function `unzippw` as a wrapper for the `zipinfo` and `unzip` commands above:

```
unzippw ()
{
    local pw=$(zipinfo -1 "$1" | cut -d. -f1)
    unzip -P "$pw" "$1"
}
```

Comment: +1 for `zipinfo`, didn't know this :->

Comment: It's part of the `unzip` package ([RPM example](https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/28/x86_64/u/unzip-6.0-38.fc28.x86_64.html), [DEB example](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/i386/unzip/filelist)), so I felt safe suggesting it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I got the logic now, not sure how to continue the loop though

Comment: That loop will only keep the files extracted at the very end which is probably what OP wants, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: It won’t even keep the last zip file!