# how to unzip a zipped file which include various zip level files in unix/linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, zip, recursive

For example my folder name is 
**Test.zip**

**Test.zip** includes various zip folders like **te1.zip, te2.zip , te3.zip**
even **te1.zip** include various zip folders.

So i need to unzip in linux at once.

Could you please let me know how to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting nested zip files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4367/extracting-nested-zip-files)

Comment: You say you have _directories_ named `Test.zip` and `te1.zip` etc.? Or are they Zip files?

Answer (score 0):

Short script something like this should do the job (please note, that you need to have a backup of your original file, as the script needs to remove it in order to process everything recursively).

```
while [ "$(find . -type f -name '*.zip' | wc -l)" -gt 0 ]; 
  do 
    find -type f -name '*.zip' -exec mkdir '{}'_dir \; \ 
                               -exec unzip -d '{}'_dir -- '{}' \; \
                               -exec rm -- '{}' \;
  done
```

On some systems it might be possible to use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm -- '{}' \;`.

- The command will go through your current directory (expectation that this is an empty directory with the only Test.zip (or whatever zip file you have) available in it).
- For every found archive it will create a new directory with archive name + _dir (to avoid collision if some archives contain files with matching names).
- It will unzip the archive to newly created directory and remove processed zip file
- Once all files are processed, it will iterate one more time and check whether zip files are still available in directory tree
- Note, that in case there will be a zip bomb somewhere inside, the script will fall to endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great candidate for a recursive script.

**Save this as a script** (e.g. `my_unzip.sh`) **Will not work if you paste to command line as-is**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

: ${1:?Please supply a file} # ${1} is the zip being fed to the script -- a little user-friendliness never went amiss
DIR="${1%.zip}" # this is where the current zip will be unzipped
mkdir -p "${DIR}" || exit 1 # might fail if it's a file already
unzip -n -d "${DIR}" "${1}" # unzip current zip to target directory
find "${DIR}" -type f -name '*.zip' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 "${0}" # scan the target directory for more zips and recursively call this script (via ${0})
```

Make it executable

```
chmod +x my_unzip.sh
```

And run it with your zip file as a parameter:

```
my_unzip.sh /some/path/yourfile.zip
```

Preserves your original file, comments inline to explain what's happening.

Cowardly, in that it never tries to overwrite that already exists.  This behaviour can be changed by updating `unzip` command to remove `-n`, to get prompted, or change it to `-o` to force overwriting.