# A generic command to extract archive files

Tags: utilities, compression

There are many archive formats: tar, tar.gz, tar.bz2, zip, rar, tar.xz and more. I would like to have a single command that would determine the type of archive I give to it as input and extract the files from it using the respective algorithm. It's tedious to remember so much extract command variants. Is there an utility to do this?

Comment: also; http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/is-there-any-program-to-provide-a-consistent-interface-across-multiple-archive-t?rq=1

Comment: I normally use `unp` for this purpose except `unzip`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I tested all the extensions you mention, but

```
7z x <archive>
```

handles a lot of them. For `tar.sthing` archives, you however still have to untar afterwards :

```
7z x -so <archive> | tar xvf -
```

Note however that for `tar.sthing` archives, using tar and letting the compression type to be automatically detected is probably better :

```
tar xvf <archive>
```

You could also use [`dtrx`](https://github.com/brettcs/dtrx) which is packaged for several distributions, and is exactly meant at cleverly extracting files.