# Is there a universal command-line archive extraction utility for Linux?

Tags: command-line, compression, archive

Extracting the contents of a (possibly compressed) archive file is a task I need to perform very often.

Depending on what method of compression and archive format the author of an archive file chose, I need to use one of the `tar`, `unzip`, `gunzip`, `xz`, or `7z` commands (and there are probably others I haven't encountered, or that I have encountered but I can't think of right now), each with a slightly different command-line syntax.

It would be nice to have a single command that can handle all of these formats. Is there one?

Note that I don't necessarily expect a single tool to know about and handle all of the formats. I'd be perfectly happy with a tool that just provides a uniform interface, and plugins/connectors that provide support for the various formats.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short of [writing your own wrapper](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7651/31256) script to 1) detect the archive type and then 2) use the appropriate command to extract it, a quick `apt-cache search extract` came up with [dtrx](https://github.com/dtrx-py/dtrx) that seems to do exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: `dtrx` is indeed exactly what I was looking for. Much thanks!